# How to retrieve Yahoo stock symbols from ISIN codes?

Tags: r, finance, stock

I have a large list of ISIN codes for European stocks. I found Yahoo Finance search feature is able to look for stock symbols using ISIN codes. However, I would like to know if there is a way to use R to automatize and speed this process. For instance, to look each ISIN code in my list and retrieve the corresponding stock symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
Yho_Search_String <- function(
    string,
    simplifyVector = TRUE
) {

  checkmate::assert_string(string)

  searchstring <- utils::URLencode(string)

  # Send a GET request to the Yahoo Finance search API endpoint
  response <- httr::GET(
    paste0(
      "https://finance.yahoo.com/",
      "_finance_doubledown/api/resource/searchassist;",
      "searchTerm=", searchstring
    )
  )

  # Parse the JSON response
  res <- jsonlite::fromJSON(
    httr::content(response, "text"),
    simplifyVector = simplifyVector
  )

  return(res)

}

Yho_Search_String(string = "Apple")
```